# sethtmlheader mpdf not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

sethtmlheader mpdf not working

i have several pages in html , i have the presences,the cover , the imagesonleft

each one has html :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

the problem its that its not printing on the pdf the header or the footer

```
$this->load->library('pdf');


$pdf = $this->pdf->load();



$pdf->debug = true;


$pdf->WriteHTML($html);


$pdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">My document</div>',true);



$pdf->WriteHTML($htmlpresences);                     

$pdf->SetHTMLFooter('
    <table width="100%" style="vertical-align: bottom; font-family: serif; font-size: 8pt; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;"><tr>
    <td width="33%"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">{DATE j-m-Y}</span></td>
    <td width="33%" align="center" style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">{PAGENO}/{nbpg}</td>
    <td width="33%" style="text-align: right; ">My document</td>
    </tr></table>
    ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should be setting the header and the footer before calling WriteHTML - in your code you have already written the content of the page before you tell mpdf what header to use.

Also, depending on which version of mpdf you're using the second parameter to SetHTMLHeader should be a 'page' value that indicates where to use the header (odd pages, even pages, all or none) - see the docs here: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=152. So you need to remove the 'true' parameter you have used as this is not required.

I actually had more success setting the headers and footers in the html itself rather than in code, by using the  tag with parameters. You could also try wrapping the header html in  tags to see if that helps.

Comment: link doesn't work anymore. check https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/headers-footers.html

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should be setting the header and the footer before calling WriteHTML - in your code you have already written the content of the page before you tell mpdf what header to use.